# PyDev 2.7.1 on Windows 7 64 Bit: Error on getting interpreter info (related to QGIS)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev, qgis

I have QGIS installed from the OSGeo4W package, which also includes Python 2.7 and a lot of spatial libraries for Python.

I have the following environment variables set in Windows 7:

```
Path = [...];C:\OSGeo4W\bin

PYTHONPATH = C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27\lib;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python;
C:\Users\username\.qgis\python;
C:\Users\username\.qgis\python\plugins;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\plugins;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27\DLLs;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27\lib\site-packages;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools;
```

When executing C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python.exe or just python (as it gets correctly resolved) from the W7 CLI, I can import stuff such as `import pyspatialite` without problems, so I assume PYTHONPATH was correctly set.

When trying to add the Python Interpreter in PyDev though, I get the following error:

```
Error getting info on interpreter: See error log for details.
No output was in the standard output when trying to create the interpreter info.
The error output contains:>>ImportError: No module named site<<
```

It's as if PyDev does not recognize PYTHONPATH. Also, under the "Libraries"-Tab, I do not see any entries (this again hints at PyDev not recognizing PYTHONPATH).

I've already restarted Eclipse, without success.

**UPDATE: Restarting the whole system worked. Gosh, we still live in the 90es.**

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the whole W7 system helped. It's still like back in the Windows XP times..